# EWS Managed API: Get LastModifiedTime after Update/Save

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Im syncing some contacts with Excahnge-Webservices.

I have to know if a contact is changed on the server. for this i want to read the LastModifiedTime after an Update.

Atm im doing this by binding the item with a special propertyset.

but that slows down my calls.

is there a way to read the LastModifiedTime ON Update/Save without a new bind?

```
// Save the contact.
contact.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);

PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
ps.Add(ItemSchema.LastModifiedTime);
contact = Contact.Bind(service, contact.Id.UniqueId, ps); // rebind the item to get the LastModifiedTime

lastServerModificationDate = contact.LastModifiedTime;
```